# How can I create a dockerfile for .deb package containing a c++ source file?

Tags: c++, docker, debian, dockerfile

C++ file with name `first.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello world..!!";
    return 0;
}
```

Below is my dockerfile..

```
from debian:latest
LABEL:first
LABEL DESCRIPTION:Print Hello world on the screen
MAINTAINER saurav <sauravgore97@gmail.com>
COPY . /var/www/deb
WORKDIR /var/www/deb
RUN ./first
CMD ["./first"]
```

I tried with above dockerfile but I keep failing..gives me the error that
the `directory "deb" does not exist`. In fact it is in the same directory as the dockerfile where I build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the cpp file to run, it needs to be compiled first, for which we need a compiler. Since the g++ doesn't come preinstalled on debian:stretch (which is what I used), it needs to be installed first.

```
FROM debian:stretch
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /tmp 
# Install the compiler
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install g++ -y
# Copy the file containing the source code to WORKDIR/first.cpp
COPY first.cpp first.cpp
# Compile the program
RUN g++ first.cpp -o first
# Set the compiled program as the main command of the container
CMD ["./first"]
```

Build it using:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile  . -t=first-cpp
```

And run it using:

```
docker run -ti first-cpp
```

This will in turn run the container and just print out:

```
Hello world..!!
```

Comment: This. You can't "run" a C++ source file.

Comment: but I want to run `./first` executable file..`@dbakiu`

Comment: Please provide the content of the executable file, and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: means after compiling `first.cpp` file by `g++ first.cpp -o first` and after running it using `./first` create binary executable file,that I want to use in `RUN` of dockerfile..thanks in advance..

Comment: The Dockerfile did exactly that, but it just used the default output binary filename. I added the -o parameter to designate the name of the output. Please check it.